# Validation error message for password field not display in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
passwordFieldType: "password",
passwordFieldTypetwo: "password",
maxpassword: 20,
maxconfirmpassword: 20,
user: {
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      
      },
      
 user: {
      password: { required, minLength: minLength(8), maxLength: maxLength(20) },
      confirmPassword: { required, sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
      
       },
```

```html
<input :type="passwordFieldType" v-model="user.password"
 v-model.trim="$v.user.password.$model"
id="password" name="password"
class="input-section-thr"
:class="{'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.user.password) }"                  
placeholder="Enter new password"
:maxlength="maxpassword"
v-on:keypress="isPassword($event)"/>
                
 <div v-if="!$v.user.password.minLength" class="invalid-feedback-register">first validation {{ $v.user.password.$params.minLength.min }} </div>
 
<div v-else-if="$v.user.password.maxLength" class="invalid-feedback-register">
 maximum 20 characters {{ $v.user.password.$params.maxLength.min }} </div>
```

In the password field, if I type 8 characters error suggestions displaying,

But the issue is once in the password field if I type 20 characters then the error message is not displaying for the password field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$v.user.password.maxLength` value is `false` when the validation fails (the character length exceeds the specified limit), but your `<div>` is only shown when the validation passes. The fix is to invert the condition in `v-else-if`:

```html
<div v-else-if="$v.user.password.maxLength"> ❌
                ^

<div v-else-if="!$v.user.password.maxLength"> ✅
```

Also, your `<input>.maxlength` is set to the maximum character length, which not only prevents the user from exceeding the character limit, but also prevents the validation from failing, so you'd never see the error message. The fix there is to remove the `maxlength` binding:

```html
<input :maxlength="maxpassword"> ❌
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

<input> ✅
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuelidates-maxlength-validation-khv3g?file=/src/App.vue:561-600)